# programmatically doing what postgres \copy does

Tags: npgsql

in a c# npgsql client can I do what the \copy command does (fast load from a csv file). I read that psql \copy invokes `COPY FROM STDIN` but I dont know how to pipe the data

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer right here

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html